# In JQuery how to add 1 to the value of quantity input field if quantity >= 10

Tags: jquery, input, onblur

I have a form field id quantity that I need to check what number is entered. If the number is >= 10 I need to add 1 to the quantity field.

i.e. buy 10 get 1 free.

I came across this jquery snippet and thought I would be able to adjust it.

```
$('input#quantity').on('blur', function() {
    // on blur, if there is no value, set the defaultText
    if ($(this).val()=='') $(this).val($(this).data('defaultText'));
});
```

after some comments i have adjusted the code to this:

```
$('input.input').on('blur', function() {
    // on blur, if there is no value, set the defaultText
    if ($(this).val()>=10) $(this).val($(this).val()+1);;
});
```

the problem now is if you type 12 the value changes to 121

Comment: Did you try and adjust it? Seems like what you want

Comment: $('input.input').on('blur', function() {
        // on blur, if there is no value, set the defaultText
        if ($(this).val()>='10') $(this).val($(this).data(+1));
    });

i know this does not work though

Comment: from your comment, chnage `$(this).val($(this).data(+1));` to `$(this).val($(this).val()+1);`

Comment: Should add your attempt to the question. You can use a ternary to do what you want: `this.value > 10 ? this.value + 1 : this.value;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the problem now is if you type 12 the value changes to 121

```
$(this).val( parseInt($(this).val()) + 1 );
```

Use parseInt